# Save information on field at chekout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have added an extra field to the checkout page, and Now i want this field to be remembered if the customer is logged in.

So next time the customer doesn't have to fill the field again.
Actually the function that remember the address, so the customer doesn't have to fill it every time.

Can anybody help me with a solution to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need to add an extra field to:
 - `sales flat quote table`.
 - `customer eav attribute`.
Second, when the customer process to checkout, this field will be shown in the extra field if the customer is logged in and has this data.
Next, when the customer fills it and press continue, you need to add code to action which used to save this field to `quote` table.
Finally, you can catch observe `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` to save data from quote to customer (if the customer is logged in).
Hope it helpful

Comment: Okay. I am just totally lost in this. There is not an easy way to do this? I have added 4 custom fields to the checkout an every one works. The information is store on the ordre, when i look in the backend.

Comment: Yes, I think the module checkout is the important module, be careful while editing or working with it